# mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist error on trying to save the doc

Tags: python, mongoengine

The class definition:

```
class PerfSDWANJob(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'perf_sdwan_queue'}

    job_queue_name = db.StringField(),
    job_platform_pid = db.StringField(),
    job_job_id=db.StringField(),
    job_jenkins_job_id=db.StringField(),
    job_status = db.StringField(),
    job_platform_name = db.StringField(),
    job_branch=db.StringField(),
    job_json=db.StringField(),
    job_email_id=db.StringField(),
    job_profiles_to_run = db.StringField(),
    job_qt_mode = db.StringField(),
    job_baseline = db.StringField(),
    job_no_of_trials = db.StringField(),
    job_cycle = db.StringField(),
    job_job_image_path = db.StringField(),
    job_type = db.StringField(),
    job_rdp = db.StringField()

    def to_jason(self):
        return {
            "job_queue_name": self.job_queue_name,
            "job_platform_pid": self.job_platform_pid,
            "job_job_id": self.job_job_id,
            "job_jenkins_job_id": self.job_jenkins_job_id,
            "job_status": self.job_status,
            "job_platform_name": self.job_platform_name,
            "job_branch": self.job_branch,
            "job_json": self.job_json,
            "job_email_id": self.job_email_id,
            "job_profiles_to_run": self.job_profiles_to_run,
            "job_qt_mode": self.job_qt_mode,
            "job_baseline": self.job_baseline,
            "job_no_of_trials": self.job_no_of_trials,
            "job_cycle": self.job_cycle,
            "job_job_image_path": self.job_job_image_path,
            "job_type": self.job_type,
            "job_rdp": self.job_rdp
        }
```

Using it like below:

```
job_obj = PerfSDWANJob(
    job_queue_name = the_queue_name,
    job_platform_pid = the_platform_pid,
    job_job_id=the_job_id,
    job_jenkins_job_id=the_jenkins_job_id,
    job_status = the_job_status,
    job_platform_name = the_platform_name,
    job_branch=the_branch,
    job_json=the_json,
    job_email_id=the_email_id,
    job_profiles_to_run = the_profiles_to_run,
    job_qt_mode = the_qt_mode,
    job_baseline = the_baseline,
    job_no_of_trials = the_no_of_trials,
    job_cycle = the_cycle,
    job_job_image_path = the_image_path,
    job_type = the_job_type,
    job_rdp = the_job_rdp
)
    job_obj.save()
```

Getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\api_server_imix.py", line 180, in enqueue
    job_obj = PerfSDWANJob(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 99, in __init__
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(msg)
mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'job_profiles_to_run', 'job_platform_pid', 'job_json', 'job_qt_mode', 'job_queue_name', 'job_no_of_trials', 'job_job_id', 'job_branch', 'job_cycle', 'job_baseline', 'job_status', 'job_job_image_path', 'job_platform_name', 'job_jenkins_job_id', 'job_type', 'job_email_id'}" do not exist on the document "PerfSDWANJob"
```